# Why didn't multiplicative functions in number theory get called "homomorphism" (with possible qualifiers)?

Tags: soft-question, notation

When I saw a completely multiplicative function in number theory for the first time, I thought "homomorphism", but no, it's called a completely multiplicative function.

And there's not completely multiplicative functions which require coprimality among its arguments.  Wouldn't it be better to just stick to "homomorphism" or, conversely, calling homomorphisms something like multiplicative operators or something?

Is there perhaps something radically different between these two concepts?

Comment: My guess is that the two terms developed independently.  Early number theorists may simply not have been talking to the folk who developed the modern study of algebra.

Comment: It would be a semigroup homomorphism, but not necessarily a semiring homomorphism.

Comment: @eyeballfrog What should be a semigroup homomorphism?  A multiplicative function that's not completely multiplicative?

Comment: If we're talking about $\mathbb{Z}$ and you say "homomorphism", I would first guess "ring homomorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}, +, \cdot)$", and second I would guess "group homomorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$".  But neither of those are what you mean, and "semigroup homomorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot)$" would be way down my list of guesses.

Comment: So you could certainly say "homomorphism of the multiplicative semigroup", but that's a lot more syllables than "completely multiplicative".